# Forcing override on a server control method

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

I'm building a custom asp.net server control and I want to fire an `OnSave` method and pass on a parameter to the page implementing the control (best analogy would be the RenderContents method).

The idea is to generate an XML string containing the saved fields and pass it to the developer implementing the control through this `OnSave` method (in the case of `RenderContents` method it would be `HtmlTextWriter` output) so they can access the string in the `OnSave` method and process it (say save it to the database).

So my question is two-fold:

1. how do I force the page which implements my control to override my OnSave method?
2. how can I pass my XML string to some variable in that method so developer can access it via page's codebehind?

Comment: Do you mean an event rather than a method?

Comment: RenderContents I believe is a method, but either or...